# Difficulty in establishing VersionInfo for existing C++ DLL project

Tags: c++, dll, resources, version, versioninfo

I have an extant C++ DLL which compiles properly, but has no version information associated with it such was the Version tab in Properties for the compiled library. The odd things about it is that it does have a .rc file in Visual Studio which is associated with the project and which seems to be correctly defined. However, whether using that file, or replacing it with values from locations such as [Adding resource file to VC6 dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507560/adding-resource-file-to-vc6-dll), [Version resource in DLL not visible with right-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852568/version-resource-in-dll-not-visible-with-right-click), or http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/XDllPt3.aspx, I still cannot get it to export the DLL info. I cannot post most of the code of the project, since it is internal, but this is the contents of the .rc file:
    //Microsoft Developer Studio generated resource script.
    //

```
#include "afxres.h"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// English (U.S.) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
#ifdef _WIN32
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US
#pragma code_page(1252)
#endif //_WIN32

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Version
//

VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
 FILEVERSION 1,0,0,1
 PRODUCTVERSION 1,0,0,1
 FILEFLAGSMASK 0x3fL
#ifdef _DEBUG
 FILEFLAGS 0x1L
#else
 FILEFLAGS 0x0L
#endif
 FILEOS 0x4L
 FILETYPE 0x1L
 FILESUBTYPE 0x0L
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "040904B0"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "CompanyName", "\0"
            VALUE "FileDescription", "PTU DLL library\0"
            VALUE "FileVersion", "1, 0, 0, 1\0"
            VALUE "InternalName", "PTUDLL32\0"
            VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright (C) 1999\0"
            VALUE "ProductName", "PTU DLL library\0"
            VALUE "ProductVersion", "1, 0, 0, 1\0"
        END
    END
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x409, 1200
    END
END


#endif    // English (U.S.) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Clarify your use of the term "export". Does the version information not appear in the resource section of the DLL? Are you attempting to access it via `GetProcAddress` or `GetFileVersionInfo`?

Comment: Hard to fumble this.  Basic check: use File + Open + File in Visual Studio.  You see the embedded resources, if any.

Answer (score 0):

Actually my question was on getting the version info into it. But as it is, the problem resolved itself. Apparently the resource file that came with the project had gotten corrupted. Creating a new one, attaching it to the project, and moving over the information served to make it work. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

To retrieve the version information from a file you need to use GetFileVersionInfo(). You should take the additional step of determining the size of the version information stored before retrieving it with a call to GetFileVersionInfoSize().

```
bool GetVersionInfo(const char *filename, int &major, int &minor)
{
    DWORD   verBufferSize;
    char    verBuffer[2048];

    //  Get the size of the version info block in the file
    verBufferSize = GetFileVersionInfoSize(filename, NULL);
    if(verBufferSize > 0 && verBufferSize <= sizeof(verBuffer))
    {
        //  get the version block from the file
        if(TRUE == GetFileVersionInfo(filename, NULL, verBufferSize, verBuffer))
        {
            UINT length;
            VS_FIXEDFILEINFO *verInfo = NULL;

            //  Query the value
            if(TRUE == VerQueryValue(verBuffer, "\\", reinterpret_cast<LPVOID*>(&verInfo), &length))
            {
                //  Pull the version values. You can alternatively
                //  get the version of the file from dwFileVersionMS
                //  and dwFileVersionLS if necessary.
                major = verInfo->dwProductVersionMS;
                minor = verInfo->dwProductVersionLS;

                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```